# Database File link field empty when using jQuery ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a ajax form, I am using the validate plugin and also the jQuery **[form](https://github.com/malsup/form')** plugin, now if I'm using the form plugin methods inside the submithandler (this is a validate.js parameter) method, like so:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        type:"POST",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        url:"inc/database.php",
        success: function() {
            $('#testimonials :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#testimonials').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#testimonials').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I have a form that has two text fields and then a file upload field, now with the above code, all the 3 fields are saved to the database, but now if I write a pure jQuery Ajax function, like so:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

       $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url         : 'inc/database.php', // the url where we want to POST
                data        : $(form).serialize(), // our data object
                dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode      : true
        }).done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log($(form).serialize()); 
            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        }); 

}
```

The two text fields are saved to the database, but the file link is not saved in the database, if I check phpmyadmin, I see that, the field which holds the URL for the image link is empty. Why is it so? I don't see any difference in the jQuery code with and without the form plugin, what am I missing here? Can anybody explain this error?

P.S. since SO states that a error must be isolated, I have extensively tested this senario and have zeroed down on the jQuery code being the culprit, and hence have not posted any backed code, as I think that would be irrelevent.

Comment: Its because when you use simple jQuery, the file is not send. Simple xhr request fails to upload the file. AjaxSubmit actually extend jquery ajax for uploading files. In your second case you dont see the data coz file is not uploaded. `.serialize` method just serialize the text not binary data.

Comment: @HarryBomrah Thanks , is there any documentation on this ? its something really interesting !

Comment: In some cases it also makes an iframe to upload files. Its usually in case of IE.

Comment: Well you can go through the code of form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form')[0]);
 $.ajax({
..
data:formdata,
..
});
```

Instead of serialize() data.

Comment: I will review this and post my comment !

Comment: Feel free to ask or suggest.